# How can I add raws to my DataGrid

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml

I need to add raws to my code.
But I am only able to add columns.
How to add raws?

```
<Page x:Class="HHT.Table"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:HHT"
  mc:Ignorable="d"
  Title="Table" Height="520" Width="985">

  <Grid Margin="0,0,-505,-120" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="805" Height="420" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" SelectionChanged="dataGrid_SelectionChanged" Margin="0,0,70,30" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="725">
      <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding XPath=@ID}"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Last Name"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="First Name"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Birthday"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Phone Number">    </DataGridTextColumn>
      </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>

  </Grid>
</Page>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string[] row = new string[] { "1", "Product 1", "1000" };
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
row = new string[] { "2", "Product 2", "2000" };
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
row = new string[] { "3", "Product 3", "3000" };
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
row = new string[] { "4", "Product 4", "4000" };
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
```

> Source:
>   http://csharp.net-informations.com/datagridview/csharp-datagridview-add-column.htm